# regrets telling him/regrets having told him

Tags: grammar, sentence-choice

**Tonya:** *Actually he's still legally my husband.*

Tonya immediately regrets telling him that. (1)

Tonya immediately regrets to have told him that. (2)

Tonya immediately regrets having told him that. (3)

Tonya immediately regrets that she told him that. (4)

Tonya immediately regrets that she has told him that. (5)

**Guy:** *He's still your husband?*

Hi. Are all the five sentences grammatical and natural?

Comment: All are possible , except for (2). We don't say _regret to have done..._

Comment: What @kate said. I can't imagine any context where ***regrets telling him*** could carry a difference in meaning from ***regrets having told him*** (not even a *nuance* of difference, but perhaps I just lack imagination). Whatever - as [*this NGram*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=regrets+telling+him%2Cregrets+having+told+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cregrets%20telling%20him%3B%2Cc0) clearly shows, we much prefer to use the simpler version.